# Microservice with Apache Camel

Tags: rest, apache-camel, endpoint

So, I have to create a microservice which takes an input from a REST API endpoint which results in an invocation of another REST API endpoint, after the transformation of the input arguments.

I'm thinking to use Camel to do such job, the alternative being Spring Boot + Spring REST etc., but I'm just a beginner; so my questions are:

1) can I use Apache Camel to achieve this goal?

2) if yes, there would not be the need to use any message broker, right?

3) if yes, would it be a elegant lightweight solution (eg could it run in a Rasperry Pi)?

Thank you in advance for the time spent reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) yes use http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-camel-as-a-http-proxy-between-a-client-and-server.html as a starting point and just place your transformations between the from() and the to()

2) Correct, no message broker needed.

3) As long as you don't add in too many components.

Spring Boot + Apache Camel is also an elegant combination.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! I'm currently evaluating the Spring Boot + Camel solution

Comment: Hey, @EmanueleMolinari, did the SB + Camel solution workout for you?

Comment: Yes, it did! Sorry for the delay though

Answer (score 1):

As Al noted Camel is very useful for creating microservices. Thought you might find this video from Claus Ibsen interesting as he discusses this very topic.

https://youtu.be/91UiQgazt3g

And if this helps here is a sandbox application I put together using Spring Boot and Camel

https://github.com/CodeSmell/MovieFinder

Hope these help